# Is there a way to get a week old data from a table were the date field is a varchar - SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting an error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

when I try to get a week old data from a table in SQL Server 2016.

The date column in my table has a datatype of `varchar`. So in my query, I try to convert it to `datetime` first and get the 1 week back result.

```
SELECT
    USERNAME, UDATE 
FROM
    SAP_CDHDR 
WHERE
    CAST(UDATE AS DATETIME) >= DATEADD(day, -7, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Sample input:

```
USERNAME     UDATE
--------------------------
User 1       26.07.2017
User 2       02.05.2017
User 3       08.12.2017
User 4       15.07.2016
User 5       20.10.2016
```

Comment: Ideally you should be fixing your data. Storing a date as a `varchar` only causes problems. A `varchar` operates very different to a `date`. For example, in  your data, `02.05.2017'` is the "earliest" "date" in that table. Although, as Gordon as shown, you can `CONVERT` the value this will have (significant) performance impacts.

Comment: Get date ()  function and you data type isn't equal.... You should use functions for change data... Like convert. Convert has 3 part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `convert()` with a format specifier:

```
select  USERNAME, UDATE
from  SAP_CDHDR
where convert(date, udate, 104) >= DATEADD(day, -7, cast(GETDATE() as date))
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bc571a1ac20e017598cd3a620fe3cb2c) is a db<>fiddle showing that it works for your sample data.

**If you have bad date values in the data, use `try_convert()`.**

Also, fix the data so your values are stored using the correct type!

EDIT:

To find the bad date values, use:

```
select  USERNAME, UDATE
from  SAP_CDHDR
where try_convert(date, udate, 104) is null
```

Comment: This solution is not working getting the error like "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Sounds like you have inconsistent formats @albinxavier333

Comment: @Gordon thanks for your input. I found some inconsistency in the date field like you told

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can convert dates into all possible values. I truly suggest that you change the data type of the column to prevent additional problems.

```
/*This is to create sample data*/
WITH SAP_CDHDR(USERNAME, UDATE) AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('User 1', '26.04.2019'),
            ('User 2', '02.05.2017'),
            ('User 3', '08.12.2017'),
            ('User 4', '15.07.2016'),
            ('User 5', '20.10.2016'))SAP_CDHDR(USERNAME, UDATE)
)
/*solution begins here*/
SELECT  USERNAME, UDATE 
FROM  SAP_CDHDR
WHERE UDATE IN( SELECT CONVERT(char(10), GETDATE()-n, 104)
                 FROM(VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7))x(n));
```